# Compass can't link

Tags: html, css

My directory `/test include`

```
html 
  about.html 
sass 
  style.scss 
stylessheets 
  style.css 
config.rb
```

when I try about.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css type="text/css" media="all">
```

It can't link.

Comment: nice link, we can't link it either

Comment: Sorry, My question format is too Bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```